# Unique id in entites of multiples databases

Tags: mysql, spring, docker

I'm developing a Web Application based on Docker and Spring. The architecture relies on micro-services with for each one a .jar compiled with Maven. Then, these jars are launched in Docker containers (one for each microservice).

The point is that I have multiple entities in each microservice, so my question would be : How to give a unique id for each entity of each microservice DB ?
I don't really know how to that with serveral databases.

Thanks for your answers

Comment: And why exaclty you need to have unique identifiers across mutliple (not related in any way beside the same schema I assume) databases ??\

Comment: Because I need to generate some references in documents which depend on these ids and these references must contain different ids which are those of my different databases

Comment: Sounds like a bad design IMHO. But in general, you will have to have generalized point for generating unique ids (if in old fashioned autoincrement style from 1 up) or use UUID as identifier. Another way would be to make composite key or use some sort of prefix. Plenty of possibilities here, but still, I think its a bad design.